# React infinite loop on change state in useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update a state inside a `useEffect`, I'm getting:

> React Hook `useEffect` has a missing dependency: 'user'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setUser(u => ...)' if you only need 'user' in the 'setUser' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

If I put user state as a dependency then I get an infinite loop.

```
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        displayName: '',
        hasPassword: false,
        ...
    });

    let { userId } = useParams();
    
    useEffect(() => {
    
        const checkPassword = async (userId) => {

            try {
                const res = await UserService.checkPassword(userId);

                if (res.status === 200) {
                    setUser({...user, hasPassword: res.data.hasPassword });
                }

            } catch (err) {
                setUser({...user, hasPassword: false });
            }
        };

        checkPassword(userId);
        
    }, [userId, user]);
```

If I remove user from dependency array than everything works fine, but I'm trying to get rid of that warning. I just need to execute this function only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method returned on the second position from `useState` also accepts a callback, so your code could be rewritten as this:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({
        displayName: '',
        hasPassword: false,
        ...
    });

    let { userId } = useParams();
    
    useEffect(() => {
    
        const checkPassword = async (userId) => {

            try {
                const res = await UserService.checkPassword(userId);

                if (res.status === 200) {
                    setUser(user=>({...user, hasPassword: res.data.hasPassword }));
                }

            } catch (err) {
                setUser(user=>({...user, hasPassword: false }));
            }
        };

        checkPassword(userId);
        
    }, [userId]);
```

Comment: didn't know I could use a callback on setState

Comment: I personally try to use it like that most of the time

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use the previous state of the `user` instead of the state `user` as:

```
setUser(prevState => ({
   ...prevState,
   hasPassword: res.data.hasPassword
}));
```

Thus you don't need `user` in the dependency array.

Final code would be with the suggestion:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const checkPassword = async (userId) => {
       try {
          const res = await UserService.checkPassword(userId);

          if (res.status === 200) {
             setUser(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                hasPassword: res.data.hasPassword
             }));
          }
       } catch (err) {
          setUser(prevState => ({
             ...prevState,
             hasPassword: false
          }));
       }
    };

    checkPassword(userId);    
}, [userId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setState callback syntax:

```
setUser(user => ({ ...user, hasPassword: whatever }))
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you have circular dependancy i.e.

- You effect runs when `user` object changes
- In the effect, you update your `user` object again

Note that, reference of your `user` object changes on every `setUser` call, that's why there's infinite loop.

I wouldn't recommend having `user` in your dependancy array as you could update `user` details if `userId` changes.

> If still you can't remove `user` dependancy, you could use `JSON.stringify(user)` as dependancy instead as the effect would run only when stringified representation of your `user` object changes.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    // your effect code
 }, [userId, JSON.stringify(user)]);
```

Note: Use `stringify()` only if you don't have values with undefined/NaN etc as the keys would be lost after conversion.